# How to create commands shortcut on Aptana 3?

Tags: aptana

Well, Hi everyone, I'm new here. And I have this doubt about how to create a command shortcut in Aptana like works in textmate. I work with CodeIgniter framework and I saw a video on youtube about the CI, the programmer was using textmate and he create some shortcuts like this: when he wants to create this line of code "$this->load->view('[cursor]'); he just wrote "ciloadview" then the line appears. Is it possible to create shortcuts like that on Aptana 3??

Answer (score 6):

In Studio 3, you can add custom snippet through rubles. You would first need to create your own ruble, and add your custom snippet accordingly.  Instructions to create a ruble can be found here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+Ruble

And creating a new snippet can be found here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+snippet

In your scenario, I would use "ciloadview" as the trigger and "$this->load->view('[cursor]');" would be the expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will see and create the snippets...thanks :)